# Update mysql data not submitting

Tags: c#, mysql

i've been working on some tool that can edit data in my mysql database everything works other than the update data say i edit the table through the program edit the name of an entry it won't update this is what i have so far if anyone could help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try

            {

                string MyConnection2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=toor";

                //Display query 

                string Query = "select * from truck.jobs;";

                MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);

                MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);



                //  MyConn2.Open(); 

                //For offline connection we weill use  MySqlDataAdapter class. 

                MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

                MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;

                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

                MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);





                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable; // here i have assign dTable object to the dataGridView1 object to display data. 



                // MyConn2.Close(); 

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {



                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

the current tables being used in the database are id,Name,PlayerUID,JobsCompleted,MoneyEarned,CargoWeight,DrivenDistance
i'm using a data grid to view the data in the tool 
here is an image of the tool 
[image: click here for image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i had to enter the id of which data i wanted to enter that's the issue i had

Answer (score 0):

on the update button's click call this

```
MyAdapter.Update(dTable)
```

Comment: @dazholmes Use class level variable and use same variable on multiple events.

Comment: i tried putting MyAdapter.Update(dTable)
 under MyAdapter.Fill(dTable); but still doesn't upload

Comment: @dazholmes Did you modified dataTable somehow?