# Login Page to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I made a login page that checks the database for the username and password but it's just allowing any  username and password it's not rejecting them not sure why I'm new to this, below is the form, I've entered data into the database with user_name and password so it's deffo not that must be something in the code but when I close out of the program it also says password incorrect which is strange it only shows that once I've actually clicked close on the program tho it's weird

```
namespace LoginApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PassTextBox.PasswordChar = '•';
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string MyConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=user;password=pass";
                MySqlConnection MyConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
                MySqlCommand MyCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from etool.login where user_name='" + this.UserTextBox.Text + "' and password='" + this.PassTextBox.Text + "' ;", MyConn);
                MySqlDataReader MyReader;

                MyConn.Open();
                MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (MyReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(MyReader[count]);
                    count++;
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
                this.Hide();

                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.ShowDialog();

                if (count == 1)
                {
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and passwor.\nAccess denied.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and password is incorrect.\nPleas try again.");
                }
                MyConn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you REALLY should use parameters instead of construct your command with the variables like you did.

Second, you shouldn't put here your user and pass for root.

Third, you will ALWAYS show the message "Username and password is correct", as nothing is preventing this from happening.

Actually, your code is like this:

```
while (MyReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyReader[count]);
    count++;
}

//This block of code will ALWAYS be executed,
//no matter the value of count.
MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
this.Hide();
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();

//This IF block is doing nothing.
if (count == 1)
{
}
```

As you can see, the code that should be executed ONLY in case the counter had a value of 1 is executed no matter what.

You need to put the part of your code that must be executed only if count is equal to 1 **INSIDE** the IF that checks if count is equal to 1:

```
if (count == 1)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
  this.Hide();
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: how would i put the code into IF i'm new to this i just need this tool to work for my admins of the community if you'd help i'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: I already gave you the answer above. Just put the code that says the message and open the new form inside the if where you check that the db returned only one register.

Comment: i can an error if  Form2 f2 = new Form2(); but if i change it to  Form2 f1 = new Form2(); there isn't any errors and the code you posted to me i have already did you actually look at the code? you just pasted the code from my post.... o.O

Comment: @daz, are you kidding right? Your code is OUTSIDE the declaring if block. I put it inside, where it should be.

Comment: @dazholmes, I improved the answer so you can understand your error.

Comment: Ok thanks i see where i went wrong but what's an IF you're telling me to put that code into IF but i don't know what IF IS

Comment: @dazholmes "IF" statement? like the one I SHOW you in the answer? like if(count == 1)? :)

Comment: Ok i see i corrected that but now i have another issue http://prntscr.com/c8fob4 not sure why it's saying } expected when there is already a }

Comment: @dazholmes, It seems to me that you would benefit from learning to code, in general, and specifically in C#. Delete the code between the 'if(count == 1)' and the '{'. There must be nothing there.

Comment: Thanks it worked <3 you're amazing bro thanks for sticking with me on this issue :D btw you wouldn't mind looking at another issue i have would you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054520/update-mysql-data-not-submitting